# Why is my wire network connection established only at 10Mb/s?

Tags: networking, dhcp

At home, I have internet access through the public fiber network. My ISP is free (a french one) that provide a box called "freebox" with an integrated switch providing 4 ethernet ports. My home office has an ethernet plug on the wall with ethernet wire down to the garage where the box is located. My computer runs on Ubuntu 20.04

1. When I plug an ethernet wire between my computer and the office plug, an then connect this wall wire directly to one of the box ethernet ports, my network connection is established only at 10Mb/s.
2. If I use another switch (which has a limited speed of 100Mb/s) that I connect to the same ethernet switch on my box, and then connect the wall wire on this new switch, I get a 100Mb/s connection.
3. When I take my computer down to the garage, and plug the ethernet wire from my computer directly to the ethernet port on my box, I get a 1000Mb/s connection.

Network connection speed is specified on the device properties :

```
$> networkctl status 2
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

Failed to query link bit rates: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service not found.
● 2: eno2                                                        
             Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link 
          Network File: n/a                                      
                  Type: ether                                    
                 State: n/a (unmanaged)                          
     Alternative Names: enp0s31f6                                
                  Path: pci-0000:00:1f.6                         
                Driver: e1000e                                   
                Vendor: Intel Corporation                        
                 Model: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V          
            HW Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9000)                
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                      
      Auto negotiation: yes                                      
                 Speed: 10Mbps                                   
                Duplex: full                                     
                  Port: tp                                       
               Address: 192.168.0.80                             
                        2a01:e0a:81d:dda0:398d:d4ca:5505:7b24    
                        2a01:e0a:81d:dda0:416a:799:3fa4:2e69     
                        fe80::e262:472d:cf2f:98ee                
               Gateway: 192.168.0.254 (FREEBOX SAS)                
                        fe80::72fc:8fff:fe57:42e0 (FREEBOX SAS)  
             
     Activation Policy: up                                       
   Required For Online: yes
```

Then I do a speed test that show what the real network speed is, and that matches what the network configuration says : [image: speed test result]

Its very hard to change the configuration between 1, 2 and 3: each time I have to wait a long time, unplug and replug the wire, change port without understanding what is not working exactly. I think that I have a DHCP issue

Here is the network manager log when the connection is trying to be established :

```
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8684] device (eno2): carrier: link connected
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8709] device (eno2): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8864] policy: auto-activating connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8911] device (eno2): Activation: starting connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8914] device (eno2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8929] device (eno2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8943] device (eno2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:24 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186724.8951] dhcp4 (eno2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
janv. 08 15:05:33 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186733.1254] device (eno2): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:33 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186733.1378] device (eno2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:33 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186733.1380] device (eno2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:33 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186733.1411] device (eno2): Activation: successful, device activated.
janv. 08 15:05:39 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186739.5049] device (eno2): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:05:39 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186739.5204] dhcp4 (eno2): canceled DHCP transaction
janv. 08 15:05:39 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186739.5205] dhcp4 (eno2): state changed unknown -> done
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8681] device (eno2): carrier: link connected
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8703] device (eno2): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8766] policy: auto-activating connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8771] device (eno2): Activation: starting connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8772] device (eno2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8776] device (eno2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8781] device (eno2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:05 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186765.8784] dhcp4 (eno2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <warn>  [1673186811.5964] dhcp4 (eno2): request timed out
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.5965] dhcp4 (eno2): state changed unknown -> timeout
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.5966] device (eno2): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <warn>  [1673186811.5995] device (eno2): Activation: failed for connection 'Connexion filaire 1'
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6004] device (eno2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6323] dhcp4 (eno2): canceled DHCP transaction
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6324] dhcp4 (eno2): state changed timeout -> done
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6400] policy: auto-activating connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6424] device (eno2): Activation: starting connection 'Connexion filaire 1' (fec0ebdf-87f4-38db-ac22-950eca00c172)
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6426] device (eno2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6431] device (eno2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6439] device (eno2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:06:51 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673186811.6444] dhcp4 (eno2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

And then when it's finally working (but at a slow speed) :

```
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6178] dhcp4 (eno2): state changed unknown -> bound
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6189] device (eno2): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6268] device (eno2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6269] device (eno2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6273] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6282] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6285] policy: set 'Connexion filaire 1' (eno2) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6302] device (eno2): Activation: successful, device activated.
janv. 08 14:38:07 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185087.6755] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
janv. 08 14:38:09 fabien-book NetworkManager[1275]: <info>  [1673185089.5987] policy: set 'Connexion filaire 1' (eno2) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
```

```
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0897] dhcp4 (eno2): option requested_time_offset => '1'
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0898] dhcp4 (eno2): option requested_wpad       => '1'
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0898] dhcp4 (eno2): option routers              => '192.168.0.254'
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0898] dhcp4 (eno2): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0898] dhcp4 (eno2): state changed unknown -> bound
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0914] device (eno2): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0996] device (eno2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.0998] device (eno2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
janv. 08 15:11:19 fabien-book NetworkManager[1293]: <info>  [1673187079.1027] device (eno2): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

I can't figure out where the problem is : is it a physical issue with a cable that is damaged (but then it should not work at all) ? Is it a configuration issue on my computer ? On configuration issue in the ISP freebox ? Where should I look and what could I do to investigate more ?

Comment: Physical cable issues such as a single broken pair would drop speeds to 100Mbps. Poor quality cabling could drop that further down to 10Mbps. Cabling is the first thing I would consider faulty here.

Comment: Along the  lined of @Mokubai comment - I wonder if someone has tried to repurpose a couple of pairs of phone cables as ethernet? Cat 3 cable and/or daisy chained wiring???

Comment: This is almost certainly not a dhcp issue.  First thing I would do is open the jack and look at whats behind it.  (post pics for us to look at?)  I might also use a cable tester to check if all the wires connect end-to-end. (Ideally you want a $$$$$ cable tester but even a cheap $10 one is likely to help narrow the scope of tje problem)

Comment: @davidgo, I think you mean a €€€€€ cable tester. ;)

Comment: But then, if its a physical issue, why is it working well at 100Mbps when plugged on the 100Mbps switch ? I suspect that the initial speed negotiation with the box takes too long for another reason and the speed is dropped to 10 Mbps and then "remembered" without possibility to upgrade it later. Whereas via the switch, the speed negotiation is done each time the cable is unplugged and plugged back again. Is it possible ?